# Retrieve data from MySQL/Python query using temporary column names not index

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

How can I retrieve data from MySQL query using column names (I am just using it by index). For example, this is my sample code:

```
query = ('SELECT Column1 as name, Column2 as lastname, Column 3 as othername FROM '
         'table WHERE condition = 1 ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1')
cursor.execute(query) # I'll get just 1 result
results = cursor.fetchall()

if not results:
  connection.close()
  ..
else:
  for row in results:
    var = row[0] # <- Here is the problem, I am using the index to retrieve 
                 # the result from query, I wanna to use 'var = row["name"]' instead
                 # but this throw me an error because row must be integer type
    ...
```

I hope that you can help me. Thank you, have a good day.

Comment: Try [10.6.4 cursor.MySQLCursorDict Class](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey in order to use 'row["name"]', you will need to make a dictionary of the query. This can be done by using a dictcursor ...

cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(query)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh, I will try that. But is there another way to retrieve data from that query using temporary column names?